# Concatenar nome de variáveis com números em Lua

Tags: lua

Estou com um problema, preciso fazer o seguinte:

Tenho uma variável que guarda um numero (x=3 por exemplo)

E tenho uma tabela como essa:

```
tabela={}
tabela.var1='teste1'
tabela.var2='teste2'
tabela.var2='teste3'
tabela.var2='teste4'
```

Preciso acessar essa tabela juntando `tabela.var`  com a variável `x` (no caso 3), ficaria assim

```
print(tabela.var..x)
```

Porém o valor de `tabela.var` é `nil`. Tem alguma forma de fazer com que apenas após a concatenação o programa leia como uma variável?

Comment: Na maioria dos casos similares é esse é melhor fazer `var` ser uma subtabela que você pode acessar com `tabela.var[1]`, `tabela.var[2]`, `tabela.var[3]`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A expressão

```
tabela.var1
```

é equivalente a

```
tabela["var1"]
```

Portanto, tente

```
print(tabela["var"..x])
```

Entretanto, considere esse outro modo:

```
tabela={}
tabela.var={}
tabela.var[1]='teste1'
tabela.var[2]='teste2'
tabela.var[2]='teste3'
tabela.var[2]='teste4'
```